# Android DataBinding onClick event not working

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

Tries to add actions to the `onClick()` event button (with DataBinding). I do everything like in the materials found on the web, but it doesn't work. The `onSetLocationClick()` method is not called.

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="location"
            type="com.example.mytracker.model.Location" />

        <variable
            name="activity"
            type="com.example.mytracker.MainActivity" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLongitude"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text='@{location.longitudeText}'
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSetLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:onClick="@{() -> activity.onSetLocationClick()}"
            android:text="SET LOCATION"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvLongitude" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    Location location = new Location();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.setLocation(location);
        TextView tvLabel = binding.tvLabel;

        location.longitude = 1.1;
    }

    public void onSetLocationClick() {
        location.longitude=99;
    }
}
```

In **build.gradle** file i was added:

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
```

I found a few similar threads but found no solution in any of them.

I will add that after changing the declaration

```
android:onClick="@{() -> activity.onSetLocationClick()}"
```

to

```
android:onClick="onSetLocationClick"
```

and declaration method from

```
 public void onSetLocationClick()
```

to

```
 public void onSetLocationClick(View view)
```

the code works fine.

However, I would like to use:

```
android:onClick="@{() -> activity.onSetLocationClick()}"
```

Comment: So where do you call `setActivity()` on your binding to actually initialize your `activity` variable?

Comment: So simple... I missed this initiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `setActivity()` on your binding to actually initialize your activity variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Remove this line in your code and check it,